# Why is this not possible "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int"

Tags: java

I am trying to populate an `array` with `digits` from an `integer` by `digit`<sup>`n`</sup>.

```
int[] digits = Integer.toString(number)
                      .chars()
                      .map(c -> Math.pow(c-'0', Double.toString(number).length()))
                      .toArray();
```

Comment: a double (can) contain more information compared to an int. just make digits an array of doubles

Comment: @Stultuske, but is this possible, what am I missing here?

Comment: @Stultuske `double java.lang.Math.pow(double a, double b)`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I know that part. But, I want each digit to me raised by the length of number of digits, before I assign it to the array. *I do not want to loop over the array at all later.*

Comment: Never mind. I missed the lines below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
int[] digits = Integer.toString(number)
    .chars()
    .map(c -> (int)Math.pow(c-'0', Integer.toString(number).length()))
    .toArray();
```

Comment: casting to int could lead to strange results because of unprecise nature of double numbers, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: This removes the type mismatch compiler error, but does that really yield what you expected? (if so, feel free to accept your own answer as you found a solution yourself).

Comment: In this specific case, the casting should be ok on first glance - both arguments for `pow` are integers within range `[0..10]`, and for these values the outputs are within the range of integer.